# Is 12/16 time signature a4 beats of dotted quavers or 2 beats of dotted crotchets?

Tags: notation

Please see this question I am asked in one of my textbooks. I am asked to add a time signature. My answer is 12/16 but the  problem is that I can't divide the bar into 4 dotted quavers because of the quaver rest in the middle of the second bar. In 12/8 you are supposed to clearly show the 4 beat divisions. Is this the case for 12/16 too? If so then how can this be right?
[image]

Comment: I'd put those two rests the opposite way round, for ease of reading.

Comment: If the two rests were the other way round, this could be 12 16.  The way the rests have been ordered is what tells us it has to be 6 8.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem The beaming of the dotted quaver to the three semiquavers is another good hint for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you correctly observe, the quaver rest messes up the 4 beat divisions, so the time signature can't be 12/16. It has to be 6/8.

Answer (score 4):

12/16 is compound quadruple time with a beat equal to a dotted quaver.

6/8 time is the time signature with two dotted crotchets for beats

This time signature clearly has two beats and the first beat is equal to a dotted crotchet, this would lead you to 6/8 time.